# Which HTML editor will validate whether I have correctly or incorrectly used for example block level elements in an inline element?

Tags: text-editor

I know for example that I cannot use block level elements such as `p` or `h1` in an inline element such as `DT`. Is there an editor that will warn me or notify me if I am have incorrectly nested my elements?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will do this nicely, but I suspect if you had that you'd already know :)

Comment: I did not know that Visual Studio validates input but are there freely available editors such as NotePad++?